# Angular ui-router setup for this use case?

Tags: angular-ui, angular-ui-router

**I want to redraw a line in a line chart without reloading it (neither template nor controller) completely when navigating from country/5 to country/7. Can this be done with ui-router?**

State

```
country/:id
```

Template with directive - country.html

```
<lineChart data="scope.someData">
```

Controller

```
onStateParamsChange => fetch data, set scope.someData
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today, there is no official support for what you're looking for, which in UI Router parlance is considered 'dynamic parameters'. However, if you check out [this experimental branch](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/tree/dynamic-params) and help us out by testing and providing feedback, it will get merged to master sooner.

Set up your route/state like so:

```
$stateProvider.state("country", {
    url: "/country/{id:int}",
    params: { id: { dynamic: true } }
    /* other state configuration here */
});
```

Then, in your controller, you can observe changes to `id` like so:

```
$stateParams.$observe("id", function(val) {
    // val is the updated value of $stateParams.id
    // Here's where you can do your logic to fetch new data & update $scope
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but think I bumped into: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1061
Is there another way to observe the state change?

Comment: I'll push a fix tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: That would save my day tomorrow or whichever day :) THANKS!

Comment: Dear Nate, I am not sure if this is in scope, but will the dynamic params update possibly work for this use case?

.state('statistics.country', {
    url: "/country/:id" ... })

Here I would like the statistics parent state to hold a dynamic breadcrumb for the "statistics section" while the country dashboard is populated without a template reload.

In this case it would be OK for the parent to reload its template but the country substate should update dynamically ...

Thanks :)